# How to solve this problem with a 'tuned' prompt in ZSH?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I have an adjusted prompt in my ZSH-configuration. Main feature is, that this prompt is colored red, so that I can easily it distinguish from the outputs of programs. My prompt is defined as follows:

```
PROMPT=$'\e[0;31m%n@%m:%~> \e[0m'
```

This works mostly fine, but sometimes my cursor switches to another position on tab-completion and some characters are left behind on the screen and mangle up the commandline. That is a little annoyance, but if someone knows a solution for this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the non-printing sequences in `%{ ... %}`:

```
PROMPT=$'%{\e[0;31m%}%n@%m:%~> %{\e[0m%}'
```

You should be able to do:

```
PROMPT=$'%F{red}%n@%m:%~> %f'
```

which is simpler, easier to read and will work with terminal types that use different escape sequences.

Comment: The second line doesn't work for me, but the first works great. Thank's alot!

Comment: @Mnementh: Sorry, there was a typo in the second line - the "F" was missing. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, now work both lines. I would upvote again, if I could. :-)